# Input Field style change in a wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

can i change the style of the input field

```
 <div id="datafeedr-2" class="widget store_widget">
 <h3 class="widget-title">
  Search Store
  </h3>
  <div id="wdgt_ss">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
   /*
  * NOTE: This JS code would be much better off
 * existing in your theme's header.php file.
*/
 function wash( anInput ) { if(anInput.value == anInput.defaultValue) anInput.value =    ''; }
function checkWash( anInput ) { if(anInput.value == '') anInput.value =anInput.defaultValue; }
 //-->
 </script>
 <div class="store_search_form" style="border: none;">
  <form action="/search/" method="get"><input onfocus="wash(this);"onblur="checkWash(this);" value="Search store..." name="word" pmbx_context="4F13FC2D-6A04-435C-AA7C-7AA2FEF6FC7E">
<input type="submit" value="Go" pmbx_context="E41A706C-6E36-4DE6-B2C3-3DF4B01B1D30">
</form>
</div>     
     </div><!-- @@CACHE -->
  </div>
```

I have tried to apply the style using class id and input field 
like Css

```
    input.store_search_form
  {  

     code

  }
```

but it didnt work

i need this search bar style to exactly as the default search bar which is above it

[Site url](http://www.fashion-drop.com/search/?word=ring)

The product search bar is a plugin from www.datafeedr.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input[type=search]
   /* your style */

input[type=submit]
  /* your style */

or add id for inputs
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vwyhm/

Comment: actually i have                                                           reset.css                                                                    label, button, input{ vertical-align: middle;}
 
 button, input, select, textarea {
  margin: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  /*font-family: inherit; font-size: 100%;*/
 }
 button,input { line-height: normal;}

Comment: make a fiddle witht html and css, and wrote how you want it

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onfocus="wash(this);" onblur="checkWash(this);" value="Search store..." name="word" type="text">
```

Then just a class to style the width. Add type="text"

Comment: actually it is from plugin php which is quite confusing                       http://jsfiddle.net/VL64L/